# Where can I find a list of related search terms?

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, bing

Does Google, Bing, or any of the other major search engines make a list or index of related search terms available?

Comment: **@C_Ross:** John's answer is your best bet.

Answer (score 4):

There is the [Google Adwords Keyword Tool](https://adwords.google.com/o/Targeting/Explorer?__u=1000000000&__c=1000000000&ideaRequestType=KEYWORD_IDEAS#search.none)

Comment: +1 - If you have some time on your hands, you can get a fairly exhaustive list of the top terms for a subject with the "use synonyms" option, too.

Comment: This tool is no longer available

Answer (score 2):

Yahoo Boss has an API that provides related search terms. Check out the API Response Fields: http://developer.yahoo.com/search/boss/boss_guide/ch02s02.html

Google's Custom Search API has related search terms in their Refinement Labels:  code.google.com/apis/customsearch/docs/refinements.html

Granted these aren't exactly the same related search terms that you'll find on Yahoo.com and Google.com, but they're pretty close and of course the same engineering teams worked on the algorithms being used.

Comment: this yahoo page is gone

Comment: @AgA unfortunately the Yahoo Boss system has been discontinued. :(